# How to "connect" three paths starting at the same point?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

The following is a rather simple question, yet somehow I failed to find a solution online.

Let's say for example we want to draw a three-dimensional coordinate system:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \fbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);

        \draw[->] (O) -- (90:1);
        \draw[->] (O) -- ++(0:1);
        \pgfmathparse{sqrt(0.5)}
        \draw[->] (O) -- ++(45:\pgfmathresult);

        \node[shape=circle, draw=red, scale=.5, very thin] (mark) at (O) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\end{document}
```

[image: Our graphic, a very simple coordinate system]
[image: A zoomed-in version]

The red circle marks the problem. If you compile the document yourself and zoom far in, you'll see that the axes are not connected---a little notch is missing!

Is there a way to connect these three paths so that we get a "full corner"?

Comment: `line cap=rect` for all three `\draw` commands.

Comment: Thank you. But you certainly meant only the first two commands; the third one would make the line too long.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course.  By the way, you can do calculations directly in the coordinates, but if you have an expression containing parentheses, you need to enclose the calculation in braces, i.e. `(0.5:{sqrt(0.5)})`

Comment: Yes, that would have solved my problem quite well if I had known to search for those keywords..